# Cellular Homology of the quotient of $S^1\times D^2$ by its boundary

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I was trying to figure out the homology of the space $(S^1\times D^2)/( S^1\times S^1)$ using a cell complex decomposition. First of all, we know that:

- $S^1$ has one $0$-cell, one $1$-cell and $D^2$ has one $0$-cell, one $1$-cell and one $2$-cell.

So,

- $S^1\times D^2$ has one $0$-cell, two $1$-cells, two $2$- cells, one $3$-cell, and
- $S^1\times S^1$ has one $0$-cell, two $1$-cells and one $2$-cell.

So by taking the quotient, $(S^1\times D^2)/(S^1\times S^1)$ we are left
   with one $0$-cell, no $1$-cells, one $2$-cell and one $3$-cell.

So we have a sequence, $\mathbb Z\stackrel{d}{\to}\mathbb{Z}\to 0\to \mathbb{Z}$. How can I compute $d$? I feel like it should be $0$ but I cant prove it.

Comment: When you write $S^1\times S^1$ do you mean the *boundary* of the solid torus? Or any other torus inside?

Comment: yeah i mean the boundary, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: in the cell decomposition of $S^1\times D^2$, the boundary of the $3$-cell is exactly made of the $2$-cell that you are going to quotient by. Therefore in the quotient CW structure, the boundary of the $3$-cell is $0$ as you expected.

---

Long answer:

Concretely how do you build the quotient using these cells:

- First, you have a point ($0$-cell), which you can represent as a the (equivalence class of the) torus $S^1\times S^1$ that you quotiented by and which is therefore now a $0$-cell.
- Then, you add a $2$-cell $\{\text{pt}\}\times D^2$ for some point $\text{pt}\in S^1$: the boundary of this $2$-cell is entirely mapped to the $0$-cell as it should.
- Finally, fill in the solid torus with a $3$-cell: all the boundary of your $3$-ball goes to the $0$-cell (the boundary of the original solid torus), except for the $2$-cell *which is covered twice, with different orientations*.

This final sentence is the reason why your map is $0$ as you expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I kind of get the picture now, but I am still a little bit confused. I like your short answer, as I see it the whole boundary of the 3-cell is being crushed to a point. However, what is the relation between the 2-cell and the boundary of the 3-cell?  Are they related in any way?

Comment: @JimRohn Yes if you think of a $3$-ball, *before* it fills into the solid torus, then the parts of its boundary that are going to be mapped to the $2$-cell are two disjoint discs somewhere on the boundary. But they are going to be mapped with opposite orientations, so the algebraic boundary is $0$. (the rest of the boundary of the $3$-ball gets mapped to the boundary of the solid torus, that is the $0$-cell, so it is $0$ as well).

Comment: Uh, I think I get it now. So, to begin with, we have a point and a two cell attached to it, i.e. a 2-sphere. Let's call this space X. Then we attach a 3-cell on that space. The boundary of the 3-cell is a 2-sphere, so we attach the northern hemisphere along the 2-sphere of X, we crush the equator on the point of X and then the we map the southern hemisphere along the 2-sphere of X but "inside out". So they cancel. Is that right?

Comment: @JimRohn That's another correct point of view.